# Undefined table _seq while table exists when I load my fixture

Tags: postgresql, sequence, symfony4

I am installing a project in production that uses postgresql.

My environment of pre-production and production are strictly identical. But it is not me who made the pre-production of the project. This is also the first time I use postgresql.

So I installed my project in production, so far, so good. I arrive at the stage "doctrine: fixture: load" and there, nothing goes.

I have the following error:

```
  An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT NEXTVAL('compte_local_id_seq'
  )':
  SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "compte_local_id_seq"
  does not exist
  LINE 1: SELECT NEXTVAL('compte_local_id_seq')
                         ^
In PDOConnection.php line 90:
  SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "compte_local_id_seq"
  does not exist
  LINE 1: SELECT NEXTVAL('compte_local_id_seq')
                         ^
In PDOConnection.php line 88:
  SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "compte_local_id_seq"
  does not exist
  LINE 1: SELECT NEXTVAL('compte_local_id_seq')
                         ^
```

However, when I look in my console list of my tables, I have compte_local_id_seq. I struggle to understand what's wrong. I absolutely do not have this type of pre-production error.

I do not know if it's useful for something, I put here my CompteLocal entity.

```
namespace App\Entity\Hydro;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\Hydro\CompteLocalRepository")
 */
class CompteLocal
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
```

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The sequence `compte_local_id_seq` does not exist or is not found in a schema on your `search_path`.

Make sure to either explicitly qualify the sequence with its schema name:

```
nextval('schema_name.compte_local_id_seq')
```

or include the schema name in the `search_path`.

Make sure that the user has `USAGE` permissions on both the schema and the sequence.

Comment: oops, the account is an error because of the translator, it is "compte", I correct the post.

Comment: Then it must be a schema or permission issue.

Comment: The sequence was created during the doctrine:schema:update --force without error return. Normally, the table has rights, right? Or is it my user who isn't allowed to use it? Is it possible? I don't know postgres well.

Comment: If it is a `search_path` issue, it has nothing to do with permissions. Investigate a little! Connect to the database with `psql` and try to use the sequence manually.

Comment: hmm ... it's been 3 days that I turn on it, I would not have come to ask for advice otherwise ;) I'll return...

Answer (score 0):

There has been a concern in managing the deletion and creation of databases. The sequence tables were not at 0, which generated the error. Resuming the procedure to reset everything to 0, the problem has been solved.